# Using a background worker to efficiently write to a GUI thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, webcam

I am using a BackgroundWorker to pull video from a camera and write it to a PictureBox on my WinForms form.  In the BW thread I simply pull a frame from the camera, put it into the PictureBox, sleep, and continue:

```
while (CaptureThreadRunning)
{
    Thread.Sleep(5);
    Image tmp = Camera.GetFrame(500);
    pbCameraFeed.Image = tmp;
    //this.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { pbCameraFeed.Image = Camera.GetFrame(500); }));
}
```

The issue is that eventually adjusting or moving the form around my screen will throw the exception `System.InvalidOperationException` with the message `Additional information: Object is currently in use elsewhere.` on the line `pbCameraFeed.Image = tmp;`

I assume that the library is trying to paint something to do with the PictureBox at the same time as my while loop is, so I switched to the `this.BeginInvoke` implementation that is commented out above.  Unfortunately that cuts my framerate significantly.  I am running this code on a very slow Mini PC which may be contributing to the issue.

What I really want is a way to update my GUI with the image reliably that doesn't drop my framerate by nearly half.  Are there other standard ways to do this?  A BW thread seemed perfect for this application, but am I missing something?

Thanks

Comment: What if you just catch this exception with `try {} catch {}` ?

Comment: Did you try to keep the `BeginInvoke` but increase your `Sleep` time? 5 milliseconds is below the precision of `Thread.Sleep` (which is somewhere around 15ms, depending on the activity on your OS), so you can definitely increase it. This should help reducing the load/lag.

Comment: Increasing sleep time will reduce the lag?  I assumed that adding more time between the updates to the PictureBox would reduce the framerate even further (even if it was a tiny amount).  I will try tweaking the sleep time and see what that gets me.

Comment: @Fabjan Not a good recommendation. Exceptions are there for a reason. It says that you're doing something wrong and should be fixed not hidden behind try/catch.

Comment: @user912447 On the contrary, you're currently telling the UI thread 'Hey, stop what you're doing and update that picture box for me', every 5 milliseconds. If you ease up a little bit on the updates, the UI will have more time to do more stuff like redrawing itself and responding to the user's interaction. That's also why you put long-running operations on a BW; so the UI can do something else and stay responsive. So if you set your sleep around 33ms, you should get the equivalent of 30FPS.

Comment: I don't know if `Camera.GetFrame(500);` is an expensive operation, but wouldn't a simple timer work just as well?

Comment: @LarsTech  right now Camera.GetFrame() takes about 16ms to complete (though that is adjustable).  A timer would likely work though I don't really see any advantages with that over what I have.  I also have a good bit of initialization code in the BW thread function that I haven't posted here.

Comment: @Pierre-Luc Pineault  I see what you mean.  For whatever reason though, when I made that change it caused weird problems with a ManualResetEvent I am using to detect when the BW thread finishes.  When my GUI thread waits for it, it always times out rather than completing.   If the granularity of Thread.Sleep is about 15ms or so I don't think I will be able to get to the maximum FPS that the camera can do: 144.  Interestingly enough, Camera.GetFrame() should be taking about 16ms to complete right now, giving me a loop execution every 16ms+5ms or so.

Comment: Can I confirm that your code in the question is running on the background thread?

Comment: @Enigmativity  Sure:  http://i.imgur.com/N1rLrFc.png

Comment: @user912447 - So your biggest issue is that you're updating a UI element from a background thread. You need to not do that.

Comment: @Enigmativity  Updating a UI element from a background thread is a very common practice.  The point of this question was to ask how to best do this efficiently, or to ask for recommendations for alternatives.

Comment: @user912447 - If you mean updating the UI on a background thread by invoking a call on the UI thread, then, yes, it is very comment. If you mean directly updating the UI from a background thread then that's something you should never do. Winforms and WPF do not support multi-threading.

Comment: @Enigmativity Okay, I pointing out using an Invoke call in my question and  discussed the limitation I found with it.  If you have any suggestions on getting around that issue I would be glad to hear them.

Answer (score 3):

If I were you I would definitely check out the AForge.NET Framework. No need to reinvent the wheel ;)

http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/samples/video.html

> AForge.NET is an open source C# framework designed for developers and
> researchers in the fields of Computer Vision and Artificial
> Intelligence - image processing, neural networks, genetic algorithms,
> fuzzy logic, machine learning, robotics, etc.
>
> The framework is comprised by the set of libraries and sample
> applications, which demonstrate their features:
>
> AForge.Imaging - library with image processing routines and filters;
>
> AForge.Vision - computer vision library;
>
> **AForge.Video - set of libraries for video processing**;
>
> ...

Comment: AForge does look very nice.  I think it would require some time to move over to using this framework rather than just using my small while loop.  However it does look like AForge can get around the FPS issue I am having relatively easily.

Comment: Just as a small update, I did start using AForge for unrelated reasons but, unfortunately, AForge doesn't seems to have a way to interface with camera's that don't work with DirectShow.  I was using a non-DirectShow camera initially so if I want to stick with AForge, I am going to have to switch cameras as well...

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend not to use a PictureBox, and instead directly draw to a UserControl surface. This can be easily done by addig code to the Paint and Invalidate events of a UserControl.

This example below, creates a user control which has a BitMap property that it's drawed to its surface every time the control is invalidated.
So, for example, to randomly render JPG images from folder D:\MyPictures, you can do the following:

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing;

void Main()
{
    var pictures = Directory.GetFiles(@"D:\MyPictures", "*.jpg");
    var rnd = new Random();
    var form = new Form();
    var control = new MyImageControl() { Dock = DockStyle.Fill };
    form.Controls.Add(control);

    var timer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
    timer.Interval = 50;
    timer.Tick += (sender, args) => 
    {
        if (control.BitMap != null)
            control.BitMap.Dispose();
        control.BitMap = new Bitmap(pictures[rnd.Next(0, pictures.Length)]);
        control.Invalidate();
    };
    timer.Enabled = true;
    form.ShowDialog();
}

public class MyImageControl : UserControl // or PictureBox
{
    public Bitmap BitMap { get; set; }
    public MyImageControl()
    {
        this.Paint += Graph_Paint;
        this.Resize += Graph_Resize;
    }
    private void Graph_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.BitMap != null)
        {
            lock (this.BitMap)
            {
                Graphics g = e.Graphics;
                g.DrawImage(this.BitMap, this.ClientRectangle);
            }
        }
    }
    private void Graph_Resize(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Invalidate();
    } 
}
```

I think this can be easily changed to render the camera images instead of the picture files.

The code was tested on [LinqPad](https://www.linqpad.net/)

Comment: Sounds interesting. What is the benefit of using a UserControl surface over a PictureBox though?

Comment: I thought that using a UserControl would be more efficient, but I have no certainty of it. Try changing the `MyImageControl : UserControl` to `MyImageControl : PictureBox`. It should work.